# Ошибка "Syntax error: Bad fd number" при вызове функции system c++

Tags: c++, freebsd

При вызове:

```
system("ipfw pipe list >& pipe.lst");
```

Вызывает возврат с ошибкой

> Syntax error: Bad fd number

Та же самая команда, выполненная на прямую в консоли, выполняется без ошибок. ОС FreeBSD. Необходимо записать в файл результат выполнения ipfw pipe list, включая stderr

Comment: Как вариант конечно можно реузльтат смотреть выполнения, например:   res=system("/sbin/ipfw pipe list > pipe.lst");
  if (res>0){
    PutLog("--ахтунг. не получилось считать pipe. Выходим!");    
    exit(res);
  }; Но тогда не будет текста ошибки.. что не гуд.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так правильно:

```
system("ipfw pipe list &> pipe.lst"); // пишем stdout и stderr
```

Про [матчасть](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) подробнее

Comment: ipfw pipe list &> pipe.lst - под FreeBSD не применимо. Правильно именно так, как у меня.

Answer (score 1):

В консоли у Вас используется оболочка `[t]csh(1)`, а `system(3)` использует оболочку `sh(1)`. Должно быть так:

```
system("ipfw pipe list > pipe.list 2>&1");
```